# react-native-svg-charts Areachart renders an extra bottom line

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am using react-native-svg-charts to render some charts. In my case i use area chart (see image below). When the last data entries have same values, there is a bottom line appearing

[image: Actual]

[image: Expected]

Here is how i render the area chart

```
<AreaChart style = {{height: '100%', width: '100%' }} data = {Object.values(chartData)} curve={shape.curveBasis} 
           svg={{ fill: 'url(#gradient)', stroke: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.8, scale: 1.002, strokeWidth: 0 }} 
           contentInset={{ top: scaleHeight(10), bottom: scaleHeight(10) }} animate >
   <Gradient/>
</AreaChart>
```

The code for Gradient is as follows

```
 const Gradient = ({ index }) => (
        <Defs key={index}>
            <LinearGradient id={'gradient'} x1={'0%'} y={'0%'} x2={'0%'} y2={'100%'}>
                <Stop offset={'0%'} stopColor="blue" stopOpacity={1}/>                    
                <Stop offset={'100%'} stopColor="white" stopOpacity={1}/>
            </LinearGradient>
        </Defs>
    )
```

Comment: The issue was with the stroke used in svg prop. with stroke, bottom margin is also drawn. Replacing that with Path component helped solved the issue. (taken from this example: https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/storybook/stories/area-chart/with-line.js)